# class org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to class org.json.JSONObject

Tags: java, json

- Here is my Java Class

  ```
  I am getting below Exception, 
  My Requirement is : Read the Json entire Json file and return it, can come one please help me to figure this out
  ```

```
    package Resources;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Properties;
    
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
    import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
    
    public class ObjectRepository {
            public static JSONObject readJsonFile(String fileName) throws IOException, Exception {
            fileName="C:\\Users\\AamP\\eclipse-workspace\\globalData.json";
            JSONParser myParser = new JSONParser();
            Object myObject = myParser.parse(new FileReader(fileName));
            JSONObject myJsonObject = (JSONObject) myObject;
            return myJsonObject;
    
        }
    
    }
```

```
        java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to class org.json.JSONObject (org.json.simple.JSONArray and org.json.JSONObject are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
            at Resources.ObjectRepository.readJsonFile(ObjectRepository.java:41)
            at Resources.BaseClass.initializeDriver(BaseClass.java:57)
            at Nimbly.nimbly_ui.SampleTest.loadUrl(SampleTest.java:29)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
            at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
            at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
            at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:385)
            at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:321)
            at org.testng.TestRunner.invokeTestConfigurations(TestRunner.java:637)
            at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:627)
            at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:589)
            at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
            at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
            at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
            at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
            at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
            at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
            at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
            at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
            at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
            at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
            at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
            at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
            at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Comment: Why are you casting to JSONObject?

Comment: My Requirement is  Read the Jason File from One Class, then use the values on that Json file in another class. If I Did not Cast IDE return me the error

Comment: Do you know whether your JSON file will contain a JSON Object, or a JSON Array? Or might it contain either?

Comment: Then use the debugger to have a look at the `JSONArray` that `parse` is returning. Perhaps it has a single element which is your object?

Comment: Yes, My parse is returning the values

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What are the contents of the JSONArray?

Comment: {
        "browserName": "Chrome",
        "url": "https://googlr.com/"
      }

Comment: That's a JSON Object, not an array, so I'm still not sure what `parse` is returning.

Comment: @tgdavies - you gave me my lightbulb moment :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not directly use org.json.JSONObject

JSONObject myJsonObject = new JSONObject(new FileReader(fileName));

Answer (score 0):

A JSON Object looks like:
`{"foo": "bar", ... }`
while a JSON Array looks like: `["foo", "bar", ...]`.

If you read the documentation for `org.json.simple` you'll see that `parse` returns `Object` and that `org.json.JSONObject` is not part of that library.

If you want to use `org.json.simple`, then your `readJsonFile` method will need to return `Object`, unless you are certain that the JSON file contains a JSON Array, i.e. `["foo", "bar", ...]`, in which case you can cast to `org.json.simple.JSONArray`.

This will give you a `ClassCastException` when your JSON file contains a JSON Object instead of an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("path/to/file.json");
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONArray jObj = (JSONArray) parser.parse(fr);      
    } catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Use JSONObject for JSON like

```
{
  "id":"101",
  "name":"Tarun"
}
```

and JSONArray for array of JSON like

```
[
 {"id":"1","name":"ankur"},
 {"id":"2","name":"mahajan"}
]
```

you can wrap it in a func. and return the jObj according to your needs.

Comment: You can't return a value from a void method.

Comment: edited, I thought i wrapped it in other function,thanks for pointing out.